# Creating a row of clickable buttons in JS

Tags: javascript, html, class

I am trying to translate this following HTML code;

```
                <div class="dot-span">
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(10)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(11)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(12)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(13)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(14)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(15)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(16)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(17)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(18)"></span>
                </div>
```

into a JavaScript function that replicates the actions of the HTML code, but I am unsure on where to start considering there are many of one class with each element doing displaying a different slide. Any advice would be great.

Comment: You can store the length of the slides and create a function which will create the span elements as per number of the slides using some looping strategy.

Comment: When you have `document.querySelectorAll('.dot')` you get an array. It is `zero-based`. So to get the first element you do `document.querySelectorAll('.dot')[0]`. And so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something you are looking for

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".dot").forEach(function(ele, i) {
  ele.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(i + 1);
  })
});
```

```css
.dot {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot-span">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly, adapted the JS to also update my current slide as well as recording to the console log, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using only a single listener on the parent container rather than one for each span:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.dot-span');
container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.tagName !== 'SPAN') return;
    const clickedIndex = [...container.children].indexOf(e.target);
    currentSlide(clickedIndex + 1);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var containerDiv=document.body.querySelector('.dot-span');

function currentSlide(slide){
  console.log('click on slide '+slide);
}

for (var i=1; i<=18; i++){
  var span=document.createElement('span');
  span.setAttribute('class','dot');
  span.setAttribute('slideNumber',i);
  span.innerHTML='slide '+i;
  
  span.onclick=function(){
    var slideNum=this.getAttribute('slideNumber');
    currentSlide(slideNum);
  }
  
  containerDiv.appendChild(span);
  //onclick="currentSlide(1)"
}
```

```css
.dot{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:3px;
  background-color:red;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot-span">
                    
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the slide number as an attribute to `span`

```
<div class="dot-span">
    <span class="dot" data-slicenum = "1"></span>
    <span class="dot" data-slicenum = "2"></span>
    <span class="dot" data-slicenum = "3"></span>
</div>
```

Now add even listener to the elements of class `dot`

```
var allDots = document.querySelectorAll( "dot" );
Array.from( allDots ).forEach( s => s.addEventListener( "click", function(e){
   var thisEl = e.currentTarget;
   var slideNum = thisEl.getAttribute( "data-slicenum" );
   currentSlide(slideNum);
}) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='container'></div>
<script>
    // The javascript
    function spanslide(slides) {
        var t;
        for(t=1;t<=slides;t++) {
            document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += "<span class='dot' onclick='currentSlide("+t+")'>test</span>";
        }
    }
spanslide(18);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a click event on the parent node, check for the target and take its index from the list of children.

```js
let p = document.querySelector('.dot-span');
p.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('dot')) {
    let index = [...p.children].indexOf(e.target);
    console.log("Element ", index, " was clicked!");
    let yourNumber = index + 1;
    currentSlide(yourNumber);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="dot-span">
  <span class="dot">a</span>
  <span class="dot">b</span>
  <span class="dot">c</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that creates the number of slides that you need, and adds an event listener to the main span so you can use event delegation - when you click on one of the slides the `handleClick` function is called and the slide number (using a data attribute) is identified. From there you can perform whatever actions you need to.

`createSpans` accepts a number and on each iteration adds some HTML to an array which is then added to the body.

```js
createSpans(6);
const span = document.querySelector('.dot-span');
span.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function createSpans(n) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    arr.push(`<span class="dot" data-id="${i}">${i}</span>`);
  }
  const html = `<div class="dot-span">${arr.join('')}</div>`;  
  document.body.innerHTML = html;
}

function handleClick(e) {
  console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
}
```

```css
.dot {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.dot:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #afafaf;
}
```